# Convenient format for validation errors

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I'm developing application with next tech stack:

- Backend (NestJs, GraphQL)
- Frontend (React, Apollo^3.5.0)

I have REST and Gql apis. I'm stacked in defining errors format for both apis types: REST and Gql. How to make it universal.

I will explain my problem on real example. It's registration form.

### Example

In frontend app I have simple react form with 2 fields: email and password. Of course, I do validation on both sides.

On client side:

- Email field should pass regexp
- Password field should have >6 characters

On backend side (class-validator decorators):

- Email ( @IsEmail, @UniqEmail - custom decorator, that is searching user with provided email in db )
- Password ( @MinLength(6) )

### Problem

I want to find the easiest and flexible way (or format) of **validation errors** to provide them to the client side. To make a simple map and show them in ui.

I found solution but it seems to me weird (because of low typing level). On backend side I make a special errors formatting:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
        new ValidationPipe({
            exceptionFactory: (errors) => {
                 // property - property that caused error
                 // constraints - type of error(minLength, uniq, ...)

                const formatted = errors.map((error) => ({ property: error.property, constraints: error.constraints }));

                return new BadRequestException(formatted);
            },
        }),
    );
```

And format provided errors for gql:

```
 formatError: (error) => {
            if (GraphqlErrorFormatter.getErrorCode(error) === 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR') {
                return GraphqlErrorFormatter.formatInternalError(error);
            }

            return GraphqlErrorFormatter.formatError(error);
        },
```

And map errors on client side in such way:

```
// Dictionary to map errors in current language
const map = {
  email: {
    uniq: 'Email is already registered',
  },
  password: {
    minLength: 'Bla-bla-bla',
  },
};

// MUTATION PROPS
onError: (err) => {
  err.graphQLErrors.forEach((graphQLError) => {
    graphQLError.extensions.response.message.forEach((message) => {
      const { property, constraints } = message;
      const [constraint] = Object.keys(constraints);
      const errorMessage = map[property][constraint];

      if (errorMessage) setFieldError(property, { message: errorMessage });
    });
  });
}
```

### Other solutions

- Gql union type for response payload approach (e.g. put errors in data key in resp object).

I know about this but I decided to use it for bussiness errors, not validation errors.

### Question

What is your experience? What approach do you use in your applications? Thanks in advance for any answer.